# UIControlEvents variable from a string

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, uicontrolevents

Is it possible to create a `UIControlEvents` variable from a `NSString` or similar? So for example, I might have a `NSString` that is called `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` which is the same as one of the typedefs for the `UIControlEvents` variable.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand how this works correctly, UIControlEvents are enumerated as follows:

```
enum {
   UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,
   UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,
   UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
   UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
   UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
   UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
   UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
   UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
   UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8,

   UIControlEventValueChanged        = 1 << 12,

   UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,
   UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,

   UIControlEventAllTouchEvents      = 0x00000FFF,
   UIControlEventAllEditingEvents    = 0x000F0000,
   UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,
   UIControlEventSystemReserved      = 0xF0000000,
   UIControlEventAllEvents           = 0xFFFFFFFF
};
```

So once again, this is if I'm understanding this correctly so correct me if I'm wrong, but you should be able to make a variable integer and pass it to the control event like so:

```
    int myVariable = 64;
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mySelector) forControlEvents:myVariable];
```

See this link for explanation of [Bitwise Shift Left](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions)

Comment: Ok, so this works. However I don't believe that the event is correct. Because it seems to only work for UIControlEventTouchDragInside instead of UIControlEventTouchUpInside when I have 6 as the event.

Comment: @ManOx Sorry, for this example touchUpInside would be 64. Additionally, see my edit for a link to a site describing the proper usage of the bitwise shift left operator.

Comment: Perfect. I actually ended up just doing a bit wise shift like so: UIControlEvents eventForSelector = 1 << 6; Also, I'm wondering about how to do these type of events: 0xFFFFFFFF?

Comment: and you can pass those directly to the button as well, e.g: `forControlEvents:0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: @NSPostWhenldle thanks, but what type of variable is that? It appears to be hex, but how can I declare a hex value in Objective-C?

Comment: @ManOx I'm sorry to say, I don't have the answer to that question.

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF` is a literal 64-bit integer, just like `4294967295`. They have the same value, but one is written in hexadecimal and one is written in decimal. You can initialize or assign either representation to a regular `NSUInteger`. @ManOx

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create your own dictionary to map from one to the other:

```
NSDictionary * const controlEventTypesFromStrings = @{
     @"UIControlEventTouchDown" : @(UIControlEventTouchDown),
     @"UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat" : @(UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat),

     //etc.
```

<sub>This is the still-newish [Clang literal syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html); you can of course make the dictionary using the old/standard `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:UIControlEventTouchDown], @"UIControlEventTouchDown", ...`</sub>

Then with your string, you'll get an `NSNumber` from the dictionary:

```
NSNumber * eventTypeNum = controlEventTypesFromStrings[stringDescribingControlEvent];
UIControlEvents eventType = [eventTypeNum unsignedIntegerValue];
```

<sub>Retrieving the `NSNumber` would be done via `objectForKey:` if you're not using the new subscripting syntax.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here's some quick code that describes the bits in a UIControlEvents bitmask:

```
- (NSString *)describeEvents:(UIControlEvents)event {
    NSDictionary *events = @{@0: @"UIControlEventTouchDown",
                             @1: @"UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat",
                             @2: @"UIControlEventTouchDragInside",
                             @3: @"UIControlEventTouchDragOutside",
                             @4: @"UIControlEventTouchDragEnter",
                             @5: @"UIControlEventTouchDragExit",
                             @6: @"UIControlEventTouchUpInside",
                             @7: @"UIControlEventTouchUpOutside",
                             @8: @"UIControlEventTouchCancel",

                             @12: @"UIControlEventValueChanged",
                             @13: @"UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered",

                             @16: @"UIControlEventEditingDidBegin",
                             @17: @"UIControlEventEditingChanged",
                             @18: @"UIControlEventEditingDidEnd",
                             @19: @"UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit"};

    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(UIControlEvents) * CHAR_BIT; i++) {
        if((event & ((NSUInteger)1 << i)) != 0) {
            NSString *eventName = [events objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
            if(!eventName)
                eventName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];

            if(result.length > 0)
                [result appendString:@", "];
            [result appendString:eventName];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Example output:

```
[self describeEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel] // UIControlEventTouchCancel

[self describeEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents] // UIControlEventTouchDown, UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat, UIControlEventTouchDragInside, UIControlEventTouchDragOutside, UIControlEventTouchDragEnter, UIControlEventTouchDragExit, UIControlEventTouchUpInside, UIControlEventTouchUpOutside, UIControlEventTouchCancel, 9, 10, 11

[self describeEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents] // UIControlEventTouchDown, UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat, UIControlEventTouchDragInside, UIControlEventTouchDragOutside, UIControlEventTouchDragEnter, UIControlEventTouchDragExit, UIControlEventTouchUpInside, UIControlEventTouchUpOutside, UIControlEventTouchCancel, 9, 10, 11, UIControlEventValueChanged, UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered, 14, 15, UIControlEventEditingDidBegin, UIControlEventEditingChanged, UIControlEventEditingDidEnd, UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31
```